Continuity of the distance function for a fixed point in a metric space
Could anyone check this proof for any issues? I have a midterm tomorrow and I'm not sure if this proof is correct, thank you, any help is greatly appreciated!
Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space. Then, for any $x_0 \in X$, we will show that $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$, given by
$$f(x) = d(x_0, x)$$
is continuous on $X$. Let $c \in X$, $\epsilon > 0$, and let $\delta = \epsilon$. Then, for all $x \in X$ such that $d(x, c) < \delta$ we have
\begin{align*}
d(x_0, x) &\leq d(x_0, c) + d(x, c) \\
d(x_0, x) - d(x_0, c) &\leq d(x, c) \\
|d(x_0, x) - d(x_0, c)| &\leq d(x, c) \\
|d(x_0, x) - d(x_0, c)| &< \epsilon \\
|f(x) - f(c)| &< \epsilon
\end{align*}
Therefore, we have shown that when $d(x, c) < \delta$, we have $|f(x) - f(c)| < \epsilon$, so $f$ is continuous on $X$.

You have to explain how you get $|d(x_0, x) - d(x_0, c)| \leq d(x, c)$ from $d(x_0, x) - d(x_0, c)\leq d(x, c)$.
